# TypeScript Generics: Extending a Provided Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to use generics for an Angular service so that people can pass in an array of any interface/class/type they want, but I want the passed in type to extend an interface provided by the service. It's confusing to write, but here's what the service looks like so far:

```
export interface ProvidedInterface {
  stepId: number;
  parentId: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class ManagerService {
  private myModelBs: BehaviorSubject<Array<Array<T extends ProvidedInterface>>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Array<T extends ProvidedInterface>>>(null);
  constructor() {}
}
```

So the `BehaviorSubject` will contain a multidimensional array, where each element in the array is an array of the generic type that extends the `ProvidedInterface`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. VS Code has underlined `T` with red squiggly lines, saying it can't find the name "T", and the first `>` after the nested `Array` type declaration (there are three in a row; the first of those is what I'm referring to) is underlined as well and says "? expected".

Maybe I'm doing this incorrectly, but my thought was that to make this service reusable, I could use generics that extend this provided interface, and then the service won't rely on any other fields other than those in the provided interface.

Hopefully it makes sense what I'm trying to do, but I'm unsure why VS Code doesn't like `T` for a generic in the first place; as far as I can tell that should work at least even if the rest doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
export interface ProvidedInterface {
  stepId: number;
  parentId: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class ManagerService<T extends ProvidedInterface> {
  private myModelBs: BehaviorSubject<Array<Array<T>>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Array<T>>>(null);
    constructor() {}

}
```

Notice that the type declaration is now after the name of the service, `ManagerService`. Then on the type declaration for the `BehaviorSubject` all that's needed for the type is the `T`.